# How to model missing statistics in an actuarial table of age related mortality rates?

Tags: modeling, dataset

This is more of a historical related question. Edmond Halley in 1693 published an [actuarial table](http://www.pierre-marteau.com/editions/1693-mortality.html) showing mortality rates. The tables show yearly statistics for ages 1-84 and a summary statistic for ages 84-100. I have searched hard for the missing data, but with no luck (See also [Geoffrey Heywood's](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=1994QJRAS..35..151H&db_key=AST&page_ind=0&data_type=GIF&type=SCREEN_VIEW&classic=YES) article).

So this question has two parts:

- Can anyone point me to a different source showing the original paper?
- What would be the best model to generate the missing statistics between these years?

Comment: As I see [the table](http://www.pierre-marteau.com/editions/1693-mortality.html) and [the graph](http://www.pierre-marteau.com/editions/1693-mortality.html) (I don't know if it's the right one, but suppose that, it is linked from ) the data for age 84+ are insufficient (the graph line starts to bend). They cleary know why they cut it there. I think I wouldn't try to extrapolate in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gompertz (1825) - log hazard linear in age - and Makeham (1860) models (adding a constant to that exponentially increasing hazard) were used pretty successfully for mortality in their time, at least at adult ages. They don't work as well now (but mortality has changed a lot).

My first inclination would be to try simple models like those for mortality, and check them for fit. The logit of $q_x$ should behave similarly to log-hazard. If you need the whole life table in a functional form, perhaps a Heligman-Pollard model or if just a good fit is needed something using splines (as is often used these days to model mortality).

There are whole books on modelling mortality; it's not a subject you can properly cover in ten lines.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a sensible approach could be the Brass logit model. You calibrate $ln(p^{target}_t)=a+b*ln(p^{base}_t)$ being target and base an incomplete and a complete table. Then you can complete the missing $p_t^{target}$ thanks to the calibrated model.

Comment: You have not explained what you mean with $p^{target}_t$ and $p^{base}_t$. In the question the O.P. has only one mortality rate per year ($p_t$).

Comment: p^{target}s come from the yearly statistics, p^{base} come from another life table. The Brass logit model assumes that the log - linear relationship holds between two life table. It could provide a sensible approximation.